# Need to use join in the where clause of a update statement in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I need to join multiple tables in the `where` clause of a `update` statement. Precisely there are two tables with master slave relationship. I need to update a row in the master table but need to check for the foreign key entry in its slave table.

Table A

```
TableId,Empid,EmpName,EmpAdd
```

Table B

```
TableId,Empid,DeptId,DeptName
```

When a row is inserted in Table A, Table B also has an insert. Say I need to update `EmpAdd` of `TableA` and this shall be based on the columns `Empid,DeptId,DeptName` from the two tables. Therefore I guess I need to join two tables.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Add table definitions, sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: No tables, no data, no insight.  Kinda like no shoes, no service, but for databases.

Comment: That seems to me as a job for a Trigger on the table

Comment: Well i was going to use a trigger but someone just told me it can be done in the update statement itself.

Comment: Please post an example of data before/after the update you need

Comment: @Shivayan Triggers are commonly used to perform auditing actions, to maintain table integrity in place of native constraints such as foreign keys and check constraints... Triggers can be written to act on a table action such as an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE ( in SQL )... Please see the link below  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

what about checking for EXISTS instead of JOINs:

```
UPDATE tbl_master m
   SET m.some_column = some_value
 WHERE m.masteID = updatetable_id
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_slave s WHERE s.masterID = m.masterID)
```